# Average range between multiple unique number pairs in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, average

Suppose I have the following data in exce l:

[image]

For each row, I want to know what the average range between each unique pair of variables is.

Is there a way to do this in one go, without having to manually calculate the range between every number pair?

Taking row one as an example, the unique pairs and their ranges are as follows:

```
8 - 5 = 3  
8 - 6 = 2  
6 - 5 = 1  
The average range is (3 + 2 + 1)/3 = 2.
```

So, the output should be 2, but I want to know if there is a way to do this all in one formula

Comment: What should be the result of each of the examples and how is it calculated?

Comment: Edit your question please

Comment: Taking row one as an example, the unique pairs and their ranges are as follows:
5 & 8; Range = 3
8 & 6; Range = 2
5 & 6; Range = 1

The average range is (3 + 2 + 1)/3 = 2. 
So, the output should be 2, but I want to know if there is a way to do this all in one formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following array formula into cell `D1` and drag down as far as necessary:

```
= SUM(ABS(A1:C1-TRANSPOSE(A1:C1)))/(COLUMNS(A1:C1)*(COLUMNS(A1:C1)-1))
```

(Obviously, you'll have to change the formula above to whatever your cell ranges are.)

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard when entering this formula rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See below for a demonstration that this formula works.

[image]

As in the example in your question, the result for the first row is 2.

Second row:

```
10 - 1 = 9
 3 - 1 = 2
10 - 3 = 7

(9+2+7)/3 = 18/3 = 6
```

Also note, this formula works for variable column ranges. (It doesn't just have to be 3 columns.) See below for an example with 4 columns. (The formula is in cell `E1` and is evaluating over cell range `A1:D1`.)

[image]

```
 8 -  2 =  6
13 -  2 = 11
11 -  2 =  9
13 -  8 =  5
11 -  8 =  3
13 - 11 =  2

(6+11+9+5+3+2)/6 = 36/6 = 6
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: @WadeByronProfe You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.